# Can I script a Cygwin install to include certain packages?

Tags: installation, cygwin

I install cygwin frequently enough that it would be handy to have the process automated. Specifically, I want to be able to specify ahead of time the packages that I want to install, so that I don't have to remember them at install-time. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Assuming you haven't installed Cygwin yet, bash isn't available, so you have to use a CMD script.  Here's an example:

```
setup-x86.exe ^
--quiet-mode ^
--packages ^
aria2,^
atool,^
autoconf,^
...
xmlstarlet,^
zip
```

and add other packages to the list.  The caret (`^`) character at the end of every line is the line continuation character in CMD scripts.  The list of package names is comma-delimited, which is what the `--packages` option expects, although that's not documented.

You can run `setup-x86.exe --help`, or see the [Cygwin FAQ](http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli), to read about the available command line options for setup.

If you name this script, say, setup.bat or setup.cmd, and put it in the same directory as setup-x86.exe, then you can run it to get a one-click install of Cygwin with all of the packages you want.

Note also that you'll have to specify the `--site` and `--root` options for a fresh install, or it will kick out of "quiet mode" and prompt the user anyway.

Comment: worked as a dream would add, this oneliner, that saves the cygwin installation restore/replicate script:
{ echo -e "setup.exe ^\n--quiet-mode ^\n--packages ^" ; cygcheck -c | awk  '{ print $1",^"; }' ; } | u2d >cygwin_restore.bat;

Comment: How does this select the mirrors? Also where does it install cygwin?

Comment: Thats's great thanks.

Is there a way to specify which version of a package I would like to install eg rsync 3.1.0-1 instead of rsync 3.0.9-1?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  You could try specifying packages as e.g. `rsync=3.1.0-1`, or ask on the Cygwin list.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (2015-05-23 version 2.870). Clean Windows installation, downloaded the `.exe`, provided the above commandline. A brief flash, nothing downloaded, nothing installed.

Comment: @Anthon: It works for me with that setup version. On a new installation you should probably remove `--quiet-mode` the first time, in order to choose a mirror. Adding `--no-admin` will also avoid the UAC prompt if you're installing into your personal file space.

Comment: I think the arguments to `--packages` *may* need to be *comma-separated* not space separated, e.g. `--packages foo,bar,baz,quz` *not* `--packages foo, bar, baz, qux` or `--packages foo bar baz qux`

Comment: Yes, commas and no spaces.  The solution here does that, but using line continuation to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

[apt-cyg](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/projects/apt-cyg/) is similar to what I was looking for, although it requires a pre-existing cygwin install with a few non-default packages.

Comment: https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg/issues is the supported fork of `apt-cyg` in 2017-2020.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can script it, but I found a 'how-to' on making a custom package directory and the installer to go with it. This way, you can have all the packages you need and have the installer pre-selected. 
You can find that article [here](http://buildchimp.com/wordpress/?p=4).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but this would work. I may combine it with apt-cyg.

Comment: This answer isn't very useful now that the link has broken