# Cygwin install from cmd find a package for liblapack0

Tags: command-line, cygwin, lapack, apt-get, package-managers

After seeing the method of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745275/c), I was trying to install `liblapack0` in `cygwin` from the command line:

```
setup-x86.exe ^
--quiet-mode ^
--packages ^
liblapack0
```

But it seems it does not work. While I can see `liblapack0` in the GUI of `cygwin`. Even, in `ubuntu` via apt-get, I cannot install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liblapack0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package liblapack0
```

My question is that if I have the name of an item in `cygwin` GUI, how can I find its related package?

Comment: It sounds like you already have Cygwin installed.  Have you tried using [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)?

Comment: @pak, I have not installed Cygwin yet. using `apt-get` was the example code I run in my Ubuntu not on my windows