# Install Cygwin SSH during CloudFormation on Windows EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, cygwin

I provision a Windows EC2 with CloudFormation and I'd like to install Cygwin SSH on it. Cygwin is scriptable according to [Can I script a Cygwin install to include certain packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745275/can-i-script-a-cygwin-install-to-include-certain-packages/7366200#7366200). I tried with `setup-x86_64.exe --quiet-mode --packages ssh`, but I still got a dialog to choose the mirror URL.

What would be the correct command line?

Answer (score -1):

you can use powershell scripting in userdata section to install this. In your cft add these code in UserData section

```
"UserData":
{
"FN::Base64": {
"Fn::Join":[
"",
[
"<powershell> \n",
"Start-Process filepath /v /qn \n",
"</powershell> \n"
]
]
}
}
```

file path can be ebs volume where u save the exe file(full path till.exe) or can use wget or invoke-webrequest to download the file from internet and then use the Start-Process to install it